# How to show multiple numbers under "Mobile" label in android contact provider?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, contacts, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

Usually there are different numbers in a single contact under different labels such as Mobile , Work , Home , Fax etc . and i can display numbers under such Labels by following code:

```
       `while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                int index3 = phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
                int type = phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE);
                int type1 = phoneCursor.getInt(type);

                switch (type1) {
                    case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK:
                        numberWork = phoneCursor.getString(index3);
                        break;
                    case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                        numberMobile = phoneCursor.getString(index3);
                        break;
                    case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME:
                        numberHome = phoneCursor.getString(index3);
                        break;

                }
            }`
```

But the problem arises when there are multiple numbers under one Label , for example there are two numbers with "Work" label. How do i display all numbers of such contacts as i only get one contact under one label with the switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really about the ContactsContract API, your code simply holds one variable per type: `numberWork`, `numberMobile`, `numberHome`.

That is simply not flexible enough to display the many options of phones/labels in the API.

You should consider replacing those 3 hard-coded variables with a list of Objects that can hold a number + a label, like this:

```
Class TypedPhone {
    String phone;
    String type;

    TypedPhone(String phone, String type) {
        this.phone = phone;
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Then you can create a list of the above object:

```
List<TypedPhone> phones = new ArrayList<>();
```

And your loop should populate the list, something like this:

```
while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
    int type = phoneCursor.getInt(1);

    String typeValue = "Other";
    switch (type) {
        case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK: typeValue = "Work"; break;
        case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE: typeValue = "Mobile"; break;
        case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME: typeValue = "Home"; break;
        // add more optione if needed
    }

    phones.add(new TypedPhone(phoneCursor.getString(0), type));
}
```

You then need to change your UI code to handle a list of phones instead of 3 hard-coded variables.